# Time Delay in Micro C OS II

Tags: c, embedded, real-time, real-time-systems

I have been looking for that, I am using Micro C/OS II Real Time Operating System. I couldn't find a way to create a delay apart from writing nested loops. Any way to do create a delay?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  You might have problems doing pretty much anything in uC/OS-II if you found trouble finding information on this fundamental API call.  The documentation is in fact Jean Labrosse's [Book](http://www.amazon.com/MicroC-OS-II-Kernel-CD-ROM/dp/1578201039), but API sections are available [elsewhere](http://studies.ac.upc.edu/EPSC/SED/Apuntes/uCOS-II-RefMan.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

`OSTimeDly()` will delay/sleep a task for a specified number of ticks. `OSTimeDlyHMSM()` will delay a specified number of hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.